# How to find a minimum from every rows(if there are many minimums in a row keep the first one ) and replace else elements of matrix with 0?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

**The question is how to get matrix 'a' from 'sum' by using skylearn?**

```
data_points = np.array([[1,2,0],[1,0,1],[0,1,1],[0,1,2],[1,1,0]])
centers = np.array([[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,0],[1,0,0]])
sum = np.sum((data_points[:, np.newaxis] - centers)**2,axis=2)
min = np.min(sum,axis=1)
a=np.array([[0,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0]])
print("The question is how to get matrix 'a' from 'sum' by using skylearn?\n",a)
```

Comment: not sure what you mean by "skylearn", (maybe sklearn?) but this only requires numpy

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) to get the index of the first min value:

```
my_sum = np.sum((data_points[:, np.newaxis] - centers)**2,axis=2)
idx_min = np.argmin(my_sum,axis=1)

# set up output
a = np.zeros(my_sum.shape, 'int')
a[np.arange(a.shape[0]), idx_min] = 1
```

*NB. do not use `sum` and `min` as variable names, those are python builtins*

output:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0]])
```